# Why the following get minimum coins for change is not working

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to write the code to find minimum number of coins to make a change. Here is my code:

```
public class MinCoinsToChange {
    //private static int q=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(getmin(new int [] {1,2,3},5));
    }

    static int getmin(int [] C,int P) {
        int q = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if(P <= 0)
        {
            return q;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < C.length; i++)
            q = Math.min(q, getmin(C, P - C[i]));
        return q;
    }
}
```

But the code is not working. Where is the mistake i am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could correct the error. Here is the correction

```
        int q=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if(P<=0)
    {
        q=0;
        return q;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++)
        q= Math.min(q, 1+getmin(C, P-C[i]));
    return q;
}
```